# Importing existing puppet projects into Geppetto?

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I was working on Puppet modules and most of the edits were via 'vim' commands. I read about Geppetto that seemed very promising, so I downloaded and installed it. I was able to create new Puppet project, but it seems that I can not import already existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'project' within the scope of geppetto has a hidden xml file called '.project' inside the directory.

If your directory contains the .project file, then you can import the project as 'Existing project into workspace'

If the directory does not contain this file then you need to import the project as a 'file system'. Geppetto will then create the xml file for you.

This is true as of version 4.x

[image]

Comment: Yes, I end up importing the project as a 'file system'. Thank you for confirming!